# change filter to get a file with and without additional url querystring

Tags: javascript

I want to get a single css file from a page, so I do this:

```
let sheets = window.document.styleSheets;
var mysheet = Array.from(sheets).filter(mysheet => 
    mysheet.href == PAGERL+'/css/my_wanted_file.css');
```

As a result I get the complete path of the "my_wanted_file.css" file.

Now I have the situation, that cause of a reload function, the name of the wanted file looks like `"my_wanted_file.css?t=timestamp"`

What I have to change in the code above, that this code will output the wanted file in case with and without the "?t=timestamp" part?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t look at `href` to begin with, if you are not interested in the *full* URL …?

JavaScript provides you with a way to look at specific *parts* of a URL only already, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Properties

```
mysheet.pathname == '/css/my_wanted_file.css'
```

Comment: href is ok, i need the complete url. maybe there is a missunderstanding. The problem is the querystring "?t=timestamp" - wich is sometime on the end of the filename. If it is, the function dont return the file.

Comment: _“i need the complete url”_ - this doesn’t mean you lose access to it, I just changed the part where you _compare_ it to filter your array. The resulting elements inside `var mysheet` will still _have_ all those properties, they didn’t get removed just because you _read_ something else in the filter callback function.

Comment: sorry - what you mean. i think i have to add or change something in the filter nearly the answear of @Aswin Kumar !?

Comment: Replace `mysheet.href == PAGERL+'/css/my_wanted_file.css'` in your original code with what I’ve shown here, no more, no less.

Comment: (And do you need to exclude stylesheets from other domains that might have the same URL _path_? If so, that condifion alone won’t cut it, but the other URL properties can be compared the same way, and the conditions joined by &&)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `OR` || operator:

```
var mysheet = Array.from(sheets).filter(mysheet => 
    { 
      return mysheet.href == PAGERL+'/css/my_wanted_file.css'
         || mysheet.href == '/css/my_wanted_file.css'
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to check whether array contains values such as `/css/my_wanted_file.css` or `/css/my_wanted_file.css?t=timestamp`:

```
let timestamp = 'yourTimeStamp Here';
var mysheet = Array.from(sheets).filter(mysheet => 
    { 
      return mysheet.href == PAGERL+'/css/my_wanted_file.css'
         || mysheet.href ==  PAGERL+`/css/my_wanted_file.css?t=${timestamp}`
    });
```

Comment: maybe there is a missunderstanding. The problem is not to check if the file is with or without the "PAGERL". The problem is the querystring "?t=timestamp"

Comment: @Greg do you mean after reloading of a page, then you don't need `PAGERL` parameter into `filter` function?

Comment: There is no problem with PAGERL. I've only check if the "my_wanted.css" or "my_wanted.css?t=timestamp" is avivable. At the moment it works only for "my_wanted.css"

Comment: "timestamp" is no fix text, it should be a placeholder for a real unix-timestampe
I thinks it should be a kind like my_wanted_file.css* ?

Comment: no it wont work, the timestamp is unkown - did you have another idear?

Comment: @Greg I really cannot understand what you want. Could your source data and desired data?

Comment: sorry if i confused, i've post a answear how i solve it - maybe with this, you will understand what i simply need ;-)  - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of good suggestions, i decide to solve the problem in a simple way.

Split the url by the questionmark and work with this :-)

```
if(mysheet.href!=undefined && mysheet.href.split('?')[0] == PAGERL+'/css/my_wanted_file.css'){ return mysheet.href; }
```

that's all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `querySelector` with contains [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```
document.querySelector('link[href*="/css/my_wanted_file.css"]')
```

Comment: looks interesting - how i can use this inside my code?